# Crystal - Compare Strings that do not fully match

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I am having some trouble with a query in Crystal 2008. I have two tables with columns that are loosely related, both contain addresses. One table column is just a street name while the other is a street name plus some additional info. I want to find all records where these have the same street name and only show those. Example below:

| Address | AddressB |
| --- | --- |
| 123 St | 123 St, ABC City |
| 123 St | 345 St, ABC City |

I have tried using a formula such as below
if({AddressB} startswith {Address}) then {AddressB} else 'ERROR'

I have also tried this with LIKE and as well as * wildcards. Nothing seems to work. I will admit I am pretty amateur-ish with SQL and crystal so formulas are a new frontier for me writing reports. Also I should note that tables are linked appropriately with inner joins.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Perhaps your {Address} column is padded with spaces, so try:

```
IF ({AddressB} startswith Trim({Address})) THEN {AddressB} ELSE 'ERROR'
```

Comment: Thank you, but still no dice. Getting the 'Error' for fields that the first several characters/words do match.

Answer (score 0):

Test the effect of replacing the reference to the column name with the static text value that you "think" is in that column.

If you get a different behavior, what you think is in that column is not what is actually in that column. For example, the column might contain non-printable characters. You can get rid of those using the Replace function.

If you don't get a different behavior, then show us the expression with the static text values. That would allow us to replicate the behavior and understand the situation.

Note: the problem might be in your table join logic. If you have no join condition, then all records in TableA would join to all the records in TableB. In that case, you need to place the fields in the detail section to get a proper sense of what is being compared to what. Or rethink your join logic. Perhaps you should move one table to a subreport, or a SQL Expression instead of trying to include both tables in the main report.

Comment: I will try that and report back.

As for the join logic both tables have another column with a common ID number that I am using a left inner join on. Problem with that is that there is sometimes multiple entries on both tables with the same ID number. So I also tried using left inner join (as well as some others) on the address fields themselves, in fact that was the first thing I tried. Problem is when I do that, since the fields are slightly different it does not match them so I do not get anything in return except one which has the same exact data in both tables...

Comment: okay i did as you recommended and it was a different behavior and I got the output i was looking for. I am unfamiliar with the replace function, i will tinker around. Thank you!